# Can't get my code to work properly

Tags: c

Task says:

> Given a string, compute recursively a new string where all the 'x' chars have been removed.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char c[50];
int xx(char a[],int b,int d){
    if(a[b]=='\0')
        return a;
    else if(a[b]=='x'){
        c[d]=a[b+1];
        return xx(a,b+2,d+1);}
    else {
            c[d]=a[b];
            return xx(a,b+1,d+1);
        }


}
int main()
{
 char a[50];
 scanf("%s",a);
 xx(a,0,0);
 printf("%s",c);
 return 0;

 }
```

As long as I don't type `x` next to the other `x` it works. Like if i type `xaxb`, the result will be `ab`.

But if I type `xxaxxb`, the result will be `xaxb`...

Comment: I’m glad you’re thankful that somebody took the time to improve your grammar, but you really don’t have to call them names.

Answer (score 1):

Your code skips over a potentially important character - a `'\0'` or an `'x'` in these three lines:

```
else if(a[b]=='x'){
    c[d]=a[b+1];
    return xx(a,b+2,d+1);
}
```

This code goes ahead and copies the `a[b+1]` without checking that character at all.

You shouldn't copy anything there - just advance `b` by `1`, and keep `d` as is:

```
else if(a[b]=='x'){
    return xx(a,b+1,d);
}
```

This way the next level of invocation would check `a[b+1]` for you, stopping or removing it as needed.